# Writing clean URLS with 2 parameters that point to index.php

Tags: .htaccess, clean-urls

Here is my url:

website.com/index.php?folder=cars&type=ford

and would like it to be website.com/cars/ford and all pages point to index.php that I will grab the params from the url.

I can't seem to get it, here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?folder=$1&app=$2 [L]
```

This is one example I got from a clean url generator but its not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` to redirect old URL to pretty URL:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?folder=([^\s&]+)&type=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?folder=$1&app=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Sorry this did not work. I get The requested URL /cars/ford was not found on this server.

Comment: Can you copy/paste your full .htaccess in question. Also where is this htaccess located?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?folder=([^\s&]+)&type=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

Comment: It located at root level

Comment: I suggested to insert this new rule not to remove your existing rule. I have now provided full .htaccess in question that you can use.

Comment: Thanks, i will test.